# Average current mode control compensation

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, compensation

This is the structure of average current mode control (source [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-small-signal-model-for-average-current-mode-based-Yu-Lee/5d2e9a59fd7c7f10d7f46d1c18c82b22b4b7fba0)).

[image]

Please look at signal \$V_{com}\$ at the positive input of PWM modulator. 
For proper operation, in steady state the magnitude of \$V_{com}\$ should be in range peak to peak of ramp signal. Is there a clear procedure (almost like step by step) to guarantee this?

I tried to simulate this and even using simple integral compensation but \$V_{com}\$ is always out of range of ramp signal.

This is my simulation result with target 3V input and 2V output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your simulation schematic too please.

Comment: And what about the op-amps - were they OK on a single 5 volt rail? And why is your reference voltage 2 volts?

Comment: @Andyaka: I don't understand your question about OpAmp. I used reference 2V because I want output to be 2V.

Comment: What op-amps are they?

Comment: Opamp and comparator models/types undefined -- insufficient information, voting to close.